# THAT4315 audio analyzer - capacitors getting hot

Tags: capacitor, audio, electrolytic-capacitor, spectrum-analyzer, overheat

I have designed a audio spectrum analyzer circuit with THAT4315 and a drivers for IN-13 bar graph nixie tube to visualize the signal level.

To supply +-12V to the opamps, the [Meanwell NSD15](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/NSD15-D/NSD15-D-SPEC.PDF) module is used. At the moment, no additional input/output voltage filtering (other than the caps on the module) is used.

Here's the schematic for one frequency band.
[image: THAT4315 + IN-13 schematic]

The problem is that the electrolytic capacitors are getting too hot. I measured around 55 deg.C using an infrared thermometer. It's hard to pinpoint the exact caps, which are getting hottest, but it looks like the ones encircled in the schematic are slightly hotter than others.

These are the caps I used:
[EEE-FK1H220SR](https://www.mouser.ie/ProductDetail/panasonic/eee-fk1h220sr/?qs=YCa%2fAAYMW00ycUeMxwp%252bYg==&countrycode=DE&currencycode=EUR), [EEE-1HA100WR](https://www.mouser.ie/ProductDetail/panasonic/eee-1ha100wr/?qs=wEytwf7f49G9xPr4Zw3pxQ==&countrycode=DE&currencycode=EUR), [EEE-1HA4R7SR](https://www.mouser.ie/ProductDetail/panasonic/eee-1ha4r7sr/?qs=wEytwf7f49GXyFJDmktfSw==&countrycode=DE&currencycode=EUR)

Any ideas about what might be causing the caps to get hot in this circuit?

Comment: Generally a hot capacitor would suggest excess ripple current, or being installed backwards.

Comment: hey, you don't happen to have a higher-resolution image of your schematic?

Comment: oh, and which of these NSD15 modules are you using?

Comment: higher res schematic uploaded. The NSD15 module is [this](https://www.digikey.ie/product-detail/en/mean-well-usa-inc/NSD15-12D12/1866-3630-ND/7705442). Caps are not installed backwards, I at least triple-checked that.

Comment: That's a NSD15-12D12, gotcha.

Comment: Are those tantalum caps? Because the polarity markings on tantalum caps are generally opposite of those on aluminum electrolytics..

Comment: The capacitors are aluminium electrolytic caps. Links to them are in the main post.

Comment: Don't know about the other, but C17 has no reason to be getting warm.  It has 10kohm between it and the only current source, and its only load is an opamp input that shouldn't draw any current.

Comment: What else is on the board, and what sort of ground plane do you have?  It may be heat is being conducted from some other high dissipation device if you have a groundplane pour geometry.  It looks like you have other parts to this circuit that aren't shown on the above schematic.

Comment: The circuit shown above is on the board 10 times for different frequency bands. Other than that, there is only the mixing amplifier for the input signal to mix left and right channel together. Other parts of the circuit (the power supply modules) are on a separate board.

Comment: Given the odd way IC4 is powered (you have a split rail, may as well use it), C14,15 are probably the wrong way around, and (not this particular problem) I think IC6 inputs are also backwards.

Comment: Yes, the IC6 inputs are backwards in the schematic. I had to lift some legs on these op-amps and rewire it. In the process, I shorted few of the legs together with the wire I used and that was causing some excess heat. Fixed that now, but the caps still get hot. I tried putting C14,C15 (and the same caps for all other frequencies) other way round, but it still gets hot. I'm wondering could this just be the way it is, I have 30 op-amps on the bottom side of the board right under the caps. Maybe they are the heat source. Anyway, caps are now at 60 deg.C after about 30 minutes in operation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the caps would see reverse polarity on the negative signal excursions. Ground is probably at 0 V between +12 V and -12 V. Use (or make) non polarized caps.